# No fax detected with HP MFP

Tags: printer, voip, fax

I'm trying to set up a HP LaserJet MFP (multifunction fax printer) M476dw as a fax machine. It's connected to a Linksys PAP2T analogue telephone adapter (ATA) with VoipVoip as service provider with a US DID phone number. Following voipvoip instructions [here](http://www.voipvoip.com/linksys-pap2/), I have set the preferred but optional audio codec on the ATA to G729a. Incoming and outgoing voice telephone calls work on the line, and outgoing faxes seem to work as well (as tested with faxtoy.net). But incoming faxes fail to be received (as tested with faxzero.com). The device notices the the incoming fax call and picks up the line, but somehow fails to connect correctly and reports "no fax detected".

I'm unsure whether the problem might lie with the fax machine, the ATA, or the voip service, but I lean toward thinking the fax device. The error message is not very informative.

The device has onboard troubleshooting which reports that it passes its "fax detects active telephone line", "phone cord connected to correct port", "telephone line current test", and "dial tone detected", all of which you can infer from the fact that it is able to send faxes outgoing successfully. [HP's troubleshooting guide](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=5245583&docId=emr_na-c03491494&docLocale=en_US#N102E5) doesn't have many suggestions for this error other than try another line or cord.

I am hoping for some additional troubleshooting suggestions. Unfortunately I don't have a second phone line or fax machine.

Comment: Many VoIP providers don't support fax. In addition, have you checked [Fax settings - Linksys ATA](http://www.voipmechanic.com/voip-fax-settings-linksys.htm)?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes, I actually asked voipvoip about this before signing up. They said that while customers have been able to fax with their service, they offer no support for it. So I will be willing to accept that the voip service is just not capable of supporting inbound faxes, if we can rule out the device and the ATA as the problem. But thank you for the page about adjusting the ATA settings. I had not seen that, I will check it out.

Comment: Let me know how you get on. If you get it working I will write up a full answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill: So following the linked instructions, I switched my network jitter level to "extremely high", my jitter buffer adjustment from "up and down" to "disable", my audio codec from G729a (which had been voipvoip's recommendation) to G711a, echo supp enable to "no", use pref codec only to "yes", fax disable ECAN to "yes". The other recommended settings were already correct: silence supp enable is "no", echo canc enable is "no", fax passthrough method is "NSE". The result: same error. Line rings, fax picks up, tries to connect, then reports "no fax detected".

Comment: Ah well. I guess it must be a problem with voipvoip :/

Comment: I will add that changing fax machine configuration of fax speed to slow/v.29/9600 bps (as suggested http://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c00302247) and turning error correction/ECM to off (instructions at http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03266760) did not solve the problem (see http://www.voipmechanic.com/voip-fax-settings.htm, a fax configuration companion to the ATA instructions linked by David).

Comment: I tried with another voip provider (phonepower.com) and faxing worked with all default configuration. So I guess that settles it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score -2):

When you phone the machine does it ring for few seconds then squeal down the line to you? If it doesn't then the fax is at fault. If it does then its conecting to the line ok. Having problems installing these now and again. Sometimes takes alot of restarting the machine to get it to work

Comment: The OP has suggested that the phone line is ringing but the it isn't connecting.